# Entity-Framework QueryBuilder and Entity Collection Iteration

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to create the following query using QueryBuilder with Entity Framework without having to iterate through the SupplierBand Entity Collection.

```
SELECT ClientSupplier.SupplierId, SupplierBand.BandId
FROM ClientSupplier
INNER JOIN Supplier ON Supplier.SupplierID = ClientSupplier.SupplierID
INNER JOIN SupplierBand On SupplierBand.SupplierID = Supplier.SupplierID 
WHERE ClientSupplier.ClientID = @ClientID
```

Supplier has 1 to many with ClientSupplier, 
Supplier has 1 to many with SupplierBand

The following runs successfully (left out the clauses for simplicity)

```
var clientPreferredSupplierQuery = DataContextFactory.GetDataContext().ClientSuppliers.Include("Suppliers").Select("it.ClientSupplier.SupplierId", "it.Supplier.SupplierBands");
```

In order to get the SupplierBand.BandId I have to iterate the SupplierBands Entity Collection in code using a foreach on the DbDataRecord. I am concerned that this iteration will be slow compared to running the native sql above.

The database is legacy and can't be changed and I want to keep using Entity Sql with Query Builder.

Is there a better way of achieving this with QueryBuilder? Idealy I would like to make Entity Framework run one query to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

dt

Comment: what version of entity framework that you use ?

Answer (score 1):

You mention you have concerns about the EF generated query being less performant than the SQL query, but it sounds like you haven't measured it. Before you start looking at how to optimize it, I'd find out if it's even needed or not; if performance turns out to be very similar then you wouldn't have to waste hours trying to micro-optimize it!

I'd start by having a look at the SQL query that EF generates. You can use the EF 6 logging feature (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx), use an EF profiler (like Hibernating Rhino's [EFProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof)), etc. See what EF is generating: is it the same query as the one you'd write? Does it perform several DB calls?

If it's the same, then no need to look further into it. If it's not, then you should measure the performance of both options (I'm guessing you care about speed here :)). Then try to pinpoint where the problem is, and if it can be solved from EF's side. It all depends on your requirements and priorities, but at least after measuring you'll be able to base your decisions on data.

I realize this is a more global reply, not addressing your specific scenario, but hopefully it'll help you.

**Edited with more details after measurement results**

From your comment it looks like you have an N+1 problem with the query for SupplierBands. Suppliers is being eager loaded properly (with the Include), but not SupplierBands, which is what's causing all the calls to the DB.

However, I see in your SQL query that you only care about the SupplierId and BandId. This may be a simplification for your example, but if not you could optimize your query with something like this:

```
ClientSuppliers.Include(x => x.Supplier.Select(s => s.SupplierBands))
               .Select(x => new { x.SupplierId, x.Supplier.SupplierBands.Select(b => b.BandId)};
```

The ids will be loaded with the mapping entities, so you don't need to eager load the entities themselves to get them. It'd be a different story if you need the full related object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have measured performance and looked at the sql that EF generates. The EF version takes over a second and generates one sql call for the none collection data. In code I then loop through the SupplierBand entity collection retrieving the SupplierBand.BandId. This generates a call to the database for each iteration. 15 sets of sql in this case. The queries run quickly, 10ths of a second but a total of 16 calls to the database soon adds up. When I do this call with pure ado, it makes one call to the db that takes less than a 10th of a second.

Comment: That makes sense, what you have is an N+1 problem for the SupplierBand query. You're eager loading Suppliers with the "Include", but you're missing another include to eager load the SupplierBands. This way everything will be loaded in one go!